# How to disable markup validation (and others) in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, validation, markup

Sometimes while opening markup in an ASP.NET application, Visual Studio's speed increases very much just because of validation or processing of markup. Although I do not need such a feature. Is it possible to disable it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Open With Source Code Editor]